# The best replacement for 'streets general natural surveillance'?

Tags: phrase-request

I'm writing a scientific paper and I want a more concise phrase. What's the best phrase with the same semantics as a replacement with 'streets general natural surveillance', which means how much the pedestrians or residents can observe the street and its events and incidents?

Comment: It's hard to understand what "streets general natural surveillance" means.  Can you give us the complete sentence that it appears in?

Comment: I don't know if **grapevine** or **word on the street** are suitable for a scientific paper.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean about grapevine? I think it's completely irrelevant sir.

Comment: Not sure if you're trying to get across the idea or *view* or *perspective*, but try synonyms: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/view?

Comment: @AfshinSalehi: "Grapevine" refers to unofficial sources of info. Rumors, gossip among nosy neighbors, etc.

Comment: fyi, pedestrians and residents do not surveil streets. Cops do. So what do you mean by surveillance? An function of police or intelligence services.

Comment: [*Neighborhood watch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborhood_watch) programs are very common in the US. Also check [*National Neighborhood Watch*](https://www.nnw.org/).

Comment: It remains unclear what you are looking for. What kind of events and surveillance? Please provide a sentence or two with a blank for the word or phrase you want.

Comment: Neighborhood watch is relevant. I mean how much the pedestrians or residents can observe the street and its crime-related events and incidents.

Comment: I could be completely wrong, but I do not think the OP is referring to formal programs like Neighbourhood Watch, nor is he using 'surveillance' in the sense of organised police or military surveillance of an area. I think he wants a term to cover the things that happen to be seen on a street as someone is walking down the street, or someone is looking out of a window, i.e. how much of the street they can see, how much of what is happening that they can see. I don't think that there is a specific term for this sort of thing, but it could be something like 'informal streetscape observations'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a street is straight and has no trees or shrubbery that would obstruct line-of-sight, we could say that the thoroughfare is **open to view** for pedestrians on the sidewalk as well as for operators of vehicles, and for anyone with a window that opens out onto the street.  They all can see, to varying degrees, what is happening on the street. They have **an open view of the street**. You can refer to the street's **openness to view** or **[openness of view](https://books.google.com/books?id=UOZLAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA246&dq=streets%20openness%20to%20view&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY7YX747fcAhWnl-AKHW7ECu0Q6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=streets%20openness%20to%20view&f=false)**.